# How to build an image of Postgres:11 with HLL extension?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to make a Dockerfile to build an image of Postgres:11 that already installed [postgresql-hll extension](https://github.com/citusdata/postgresql-hll) inside.
 Im not experienced with Docker so Im have no idea to follow the instruction of installing this extension properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this you need to:

1. clone the git repository:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/citusdata/postgresql-hll.git
```

2. Create a file called `Dockerfile` (at the same level with the folder postgresql-hll created at step 1) with the contents:

```
ARG psversion=11

FROM postgres:$psversion

COPY postgresql-hll /postgresql-hll
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y postgresql-server-dev-${PG_MAJOR} make gcc g++

WORKDIR /postgresql-hll

RUN PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config make
RUN PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config make install

RUN echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'hll'" >> /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample

COPY create_extension.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

3. Create a file `create_extension.sql` at the same level with the Dockerfile, with the contents:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hll;
```

4. Build your image:

```sh
# build for POSTGRES 11
docker build -t hll:1.0 --build-arg psversion=11 .

# build for POSTGRES 9.6
docker build -t hll:1.0 --build-arg psversion=9 .
```

**NOTE**: The version for POSTGRES 9.6 gives an error when trying to load the library. It is here for completeness and maybe somebody can contribute to fix it.

5. Run a container based on this image

```sh
docker run -d --name hll hll:1.0
```

6. Open a shell in the newly created container:

```sh
docker exec -ti hll bash
```

7. Inside the container run:

```sh
su postgres
psql
\dx
```

The output should show the hll extension as installed.

Comment: Thank you very much, and that works for postgres:11, but with postgres:9.6 it throws  `.FATAL:  could not access file "hll": No such file or directory`, I dont know which differnt between this 2 version.@MiHai

Comment: I only tested with version 11. I'll try with version 9 as well and let you know

Comment: @BảoGia I made the Dockerfile parameterical so it is easier to run it for different versions of postgres. However, it doesn't work for version 9. It looks to me like a compatibility error but I can't say because I don't know Postgres or C++.... In any case I got it further then the error you mentioned.